# How can I proove forall a b, a <=? b = true -> a <=? S b = true in Coq

Tags: coq

Is it possible to prove this `forall (a b : nat), a <=? b = true -> a <=? S b = true.` in Coq?

I tried this so far

```
Lemma leb_0_r : forall x, x <=? 0 = true -> x = 0.
  intros. induction x. reflexivity. discriminate H. 
Qed.

Lemma leb_S : forall a b, a <=? b = true -> a <=? S b = true.
  intros a b Hab. induction b. apply leb_0_r in Hab. now rewrite Hab.
```

But here I got stuck on the induction hypothesis

```
1 subgoal

a, b : nat
Hab : (a <=? S b) = true
IHb : (a <=? b) = true -> (a <=? S b) = true

========================= (1 / 1)

(a <=? S (S b)) = true
```

I tried induction on a too

```
Lemma leb_S : forall a b, a <=? b = true -> a <=? S b = true.
  intros a b Hab. induction a. reflexivity. simpl. destruct b.
  discriminate Hab. simpl in Hab.


1 subgoal

a, b : nat
Hab : (a <=? b) = true
IHa : (a <=? S b) = true -> (a <=? S (S b)) = true

========================= (1 / 1)

(a <=? S b) = true
```

The problem is that I always get to `S a <= b` or `a <= S b` and I can't simplify that.

After posting here I realized that conclusion of IHa is equal to the goal of second try and vice versa :thinking:

Comment: Is this a question about programming? It seems like it's just about proof construction and is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs to https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It's a question about proving with Coq which is a kind of programming language. Also there is a community here that answer questions about Coq and there is even the `coq` tag.

Comment: Proof construction in a proof assistant has much more to do with programming than math. Math question are more conceptual, whereas this is about finding the commands to get a system to do what you already think is possible.

Comment: Questions about _how to use_ Coq would be on-topic. But questions about mathematical proofs that just make use of Coq are off-topic. Similarly, there's a `figma` tag. Questions about using its API are on-topic, but questions about how to design with it are off-topic.

Comment: Just a heads up, there will be a [Proof Assistant SE](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/126242/proof-assistants) beta site starting in January where this question would fit right in.

Comment: It is a Coq language usage question. From a mathematical point of view the statement is obvious - the question is how do I write it down in Coq. There have been many similar questions and this is the first one for which I see a discussion if it is off topic. IMHO it is not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am nor sure if you are learning Coq and this is an exercise or if you are using Coq. In the latter case the answer is: I would have thought the lia tactic can do this, but it requires a bit of massaging:

```
Require Import PeanoNat.
Require Import Lia.

Lemma leb_0_r : forall x, x <=? 0 = true -> x = 0.
Proof.
  intros.
  Fail lia.
  Search (_ <=? _ = true).
  apply Nat.leb_le in H.
  lia.
Qed.
```

In the former case, I would need to know what you are allowed to use. E.g. this works:

```
Require Import PeanoNat.

Lemma leb_0_r : forall x, x <=? 0 = true -> x = 0.
Proof.
  intros.
  apply Nat.leb_le in H.
  inversion H.
  reflexivity.
Qed.
```

Comment: I'm learning Coq, but this was not an exercise. Yes, I'm doing exercises about `leb` but this was something I come up because I though that would be useful.

Answer (score 2):

You could try not to use induction, but transitivity of the `<=` relation instead.